# Telegram-python-Bot get user text input with callback_query

Tags: python, user-input, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to get input text from the user..
He arrive to the function after he interact with

```
 keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("exapmple", callback_data='example')]]
 reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

so in update I'm getting callback_query
after he choose the button example I ask him for input text.
this work for me I get input with the button but not with his own input

```
def getInput(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    input = query.data
```

I want to get the input like

```
input = update.message.text
```

but since I get callback_query I don't have the message..
so how I switch to message or get input with callback_query

edit:
I arrive to getInput with

```
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(getInput, pattern='example'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The response from a callback query is

```
text = update.callback_query.data
```

If the user decides to type instead something then the message is processed as a default text message

```
def main_handler(update, context):
   print(update.message.text)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, main_handler))
```

Comment: as I mention it's work for me with button..
I need to get http link the client write..

Comment: do you mean if the user types something instead of pressing the button?

Comment: I have extended the answer, you should be able to process the text message (as when the user sends text to the chatbot)

Comment: thank you very much for your help..
but I arrive to main_handler()
after I press some button of InlineKeyboardMarkup
I extend to my question how I arrive to the function

Comment: not sure I understand, did you define the message_handler and the callback_handler? Each one is responsible to handle the  input (text or callback)

Comment: I haven't define MessageHandler I know I can do this..
but let say the user need to choose button A or B
and than he type link (it's can be the same)
and I want in each function to get his input and send the link to the server from A or B..

Comment: I can do this with MessageHandler but it's make it a little tricky in my bot..
and I don't like it in any time in the process he can send link..
I want only after he press some button to let him send link

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the text just after the user clicks the button, use ConversationHandler.

Docs: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html

Example: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py

Comment: I'm tried to do this before I ask..
this work when you use ReplyKeyboardMarkup
In my case while the button it's InlineKeyboardMarkup it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

def get_text_from_user(updater, context):
text = updater.message.text # <- this is text from user
print(text)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.exe.MessageHandler(telegram.exe.Filters.text,get_text_from_user))